# Merge Multiple Folium TimeStampedGeoJson timeDimensionControl into one

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, geojson, folium

I am using Folium to plot ground tracks of multiple satellites on a map (maximum 5 satellites). The TimeStampedGeoJson plugin for Folium comes with a timeDimension bar, that allows you to control each marker separately on the map (see bottom left of screenshot below).
[image]

I would like to merge all these timeDimensionControl into one, as all the satellites' trajectories are propagated on the same time span, and the multiple timeDimensionControl bars cover too much of the map.

I am new to javascript and am failing to understand how to engage the problem.
Below is the code that produces these timeDimensionControl bars:

```
L.Control.TimeDimensionCustom = L.Control.TimeDimension.extend({
            _getDisplayDateFormat: function(date){
                var newdate = new moment(date);
                console.log(newdate)
                return newdate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
            }
        });
        map_a5d837d7e39ab8f4f2d689152da44b7e.timeDimension = L.timeDimension(
            {
                period: "PT1M",
            }
        );
        var timeDimensionControl = new L.Control.TimeDimensionCustom(
            {"autoPlay": true, "loopButton": false, "maxSpeed": 1.1, "minSpeed": 1, "playerOptions": {"loop": true, "startOver": true, "transitionTime": 1000}, "position": "bottomleft", "timeSliderDragUpdate": false}
        );
        map_a5d837d7e39ab8f4f2d689152da44b7e.addControl(this.timeDimensionControl);
        var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.61069467391732, 0.9658165798710256]}, "properties": {"times": ["2022-08-15T00:01:09"],...})
        var timestamped_geo_json_25779c6b0b60ac5707b59da8f42211c7 = L.timeDimension.layer.geoJson(
            geoJsonLayer,
            {
                updateTimeDimension: true,
                addlastPoint: false,
                duration: "PT1M",
            }
        ).addTo(map_a5d837d7e39ab8f4f2d689152da44b7e);
```

For each satellite, this code is replicated in the `map.html` file produced by Folium.
I would like to have only one timeDimensionControl bar to control all of the satellites on the map.

Any hints on how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for answers.

EDIT:
Here is a [link](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/issues/138) I found that hints on to how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer partly lied in the [link](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/issues/138) mentioned in the question.

1. All the geojson datasets must have a common timerange.
2. You need to create and add to the map **one `timeDimension` and one
   `timeDimensionControl` only**.
3. add as many `timeDimension.Layer` as you want to the map and voila, you
   can control all of your markers with one `timeDimensionControl`.